# Is it possible to use HashiCorp Vault with redundancy in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I set up a vault cluster with two vault servers. One server is active and other one is in standby mode at a time as an expected behaivour. I can access each of them from my spring boot application with configuration in bootstrap.properties as shown below:

```
spring.cloud.vault.authentication=token
spring.cloud.vault.token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http

spring.cloud.vault.generic.backend=my-config

spring.cloud.vault.host=ip_address_of_one of_the_vault_servers
spring.cloud.vault.port=8200
```

But if the vault service which is defined in bootstrap.properties is down, I cannot access vault. So it is meaningless to have more than one vault server and using vault in HA mode.

I just want to use two vault server for redundancy in my spring boot application. How can it be possible?

Note: I cannot define host like this: spring.cloud.vault.host= ip_addr1,ip_addr2

Note2: I use postgresql as secret backend in HA mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seeems there is no way to do that with just spring cloud according to [this](https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/2-1/common/config-server/configuring-with-vault.html) documentation.

The part about that is:

> Important: The Spring Cloud Services Config Server supports only one
>   Vault backend, so only one vault object is permitted in the
>   configuration parameters.

Comment: Can't we use load balancer like nginx here

Comment: @Viraj you can.. but you must read the side effect of that as mentioned in the Vault documentation https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/ha#behind-load-balancers
Officially it is not recommended by them.